# how to create drop down field in flask wtf

Tags: python, flask, dropdown, flask-wtforms

i want to create drop down menu's using flask wtforms. i have found drop down's in bootstrap 4 but i am unable to use it. i want to make it using flask wtf.
here's what i want to achieve:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wtforms` offers the `SelectField`

see docs
https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.SelectField

Example (from the docs)

```
class PastebinEntry(Form):
    language = SelectField(u'Programming Language', choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text')])
```